# Definition of an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I'm reading the book of Miranda (Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces), and in the text he give the following definition:

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, then $X$ is a algebraic curve if, $\mathcal{M}(X)$ (Meromorphic Functions on $X$) separates points on $X$ and tangents.

1. Separates Tangents means that, for every $p\in X$ there is a meromorphic function $f$ such that $mult_p(f)=1$

Well, there is a classical definition of algebraic curve, that is, it's a algebraic variety of dimension one, how to show that this two definition are equivalent?

Comment: Well, I trust it is clear that a Riemann surface is 1-dimensional. So it remains to be shown that a compact Riemann surface satisfying the above condition is an algebraic variety. This is a non-trivial result, or rather relies on some non-trivial results such as e.g. the fact that the space of meromorphic functions with prescribed zeros and singularities is a finite dimensional complex vector space.